# Duda sobre consulta postgres

Tags: php, postgresql

Teniendo esta base de datos.Que tipo de consulta podria hacer para esta pregunta, he intentado usar el GROUP BY pero no me sale, ya que si sumo y pido los nombres me lo daria separados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta que has intentado? Pulsa en [edit] para agregarla.

Comment: Ahora no me acuerdo.
Creo que era 
`SELECT a.id ,sum(num_paginas)
FROM am()
GROUP BY a.id, sum`

O algo así , pero lo que me daba no era lo que pedía, en ese caso metí valores y me daba los valores de cada artículo , pero si intentaba sumarlo es imposible que me dé la suma de los 2. ¿Cómo lo harías tú?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas unir las tablas que se relacionan entre sí. Esto puedes hacerlo mediante `JOIN`.

Tendrías que agrupar por monografías, y para los títulos de los artículos usar una función de agregación.

Te dejo aquí un fiddle completo, con la consulta y los resultados. El código está basado en la versión 15, si tienes una versión anterior a 9 y no puedes actualizarla, debes cambiar `string_agg` por otra función de agregación más antigua.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v15)**

```
CREATE TABLE monografias (
  id INT,
  titulo VARCHAR(250),
  anyo INT
);

CREATE TABLE articulos (
  id INT,
  titulo VARCHAR(250),
  anyo INT,
  num_paginas INT
);

CREATE TABLE articulos_monografias (
  articulo_id INT,
  monografia_id INT
);

INSERT INTO monografias VALUES 
(1,'Monografía 1',2019),
(2,'Monografía 2',2020),
(3,'Monografía 3',2021),
(4,'Monografía 4',2022);

INSERT INTO articulos VALUES 
(1,'Articulo 1',2019,10),
(2,'Articulo 2',2019,5),
(3,'Articulo 3',2020,15),
(4,'Articulo 4',2020,40),
(5,'Articulo 5',2021,30),
(6,'Articulo 6',2021,20),
(7,'Articulo 7',2022,40),
(8,'Articulo 8',2022,50);


INSERT INTO articulos_monografias VALUES 
(1,1),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,2),
(5,3),
(6,3),
(7,4),
(8,4);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    m.titulo, 
    string_agg(a.titulo,',') articulos,
    SUM(a.num_paginas) AS total_paginas
FROM
    articulos_monografias AS am
    INNER JOIN articulos   AS a ON am.articulo_id   = a.id 
    INNER JOIN monografias AS m ON am.monografia_id = m.id 
GROUP BY m.titulo, m.id
ORDER BY m.id;
```

| titulo | articulos | total_paginas |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Monografía 1 | Articulo 1,Articulo 2 | 15 |
| Monografía 2 | Articulo 3,Articulo 4 | 55 |
| Monografía 3 | Articulo 5,Articulo 6 | 50 |
| Monografía 4 | Articulo 7,Articulo 8 | 90 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pLPMzKYWwaZUEhZ3xD2frh/0)

Comment: Vale me vale, pero es que alomejor el enunciado, creo que es muy ambiguo, ya que no se entiende muy bien por qué lo que pide es el TOTAL de páginas de monografía, entonces no queda muy claro. Muchísimas gracias de todas formas por la solución.

Comment: @Henry pues lo que se interpreta es que una monografía puede tener varios artículos, cada uno con una cantidad determinada de páginas y para saber el total de páginas de esa monografía hay que sumar las páginas de cada artículo. Quizá hay que agregar al `GROUP BY` el `id` de la monografía también: `GROUP BY a.id, a.titulo, m.id`

Comment: @Henry revisa la respuesta editada, tienes agrupar por monografía, no por articulo.